# Dell Inspiron 1764 Maximum external monitor resolution

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, resolution, dell-inspiron, intel-graphics

I want to buy an external monitor for my Dell Inspiron 1764 (i5HD450054).  However, I am not sure if its video card supports a display with resolution of **1920x1200** connected through HDMI. My laptop has an "Intel HD Graphics" video card, but I could not find any specs for it.

So my questions are:

1. How can I know what is the max resolution supported by this video
   card?
2. How do I get more precise information about the video card model?
   (I've only managed to determine that this is Intel HD Graphics)

I've connected my laptop to a TV with resolution of 1920x1080 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have bought the monitor and yes, Dell Inspiron 1764 supports the resolution of 1920x1200.

Also I've understood that *Intel HD Graphics* is the first generation of Intel HD Graphics, so it does not have any model number.

But I have not find any specs that mention the maximum resolution for HDMI.